# The vuetify combobox menu does not hide when blured

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use a combo box component from Vuetify in my Vue application and I fill it from web api service, and when it get focused the menu of the combo box expanded automatically but when it lost focus the menu still expanded.

Answer (score 0):

example is put the v-menu in a sheet and add the class for hide on breakpoints the you want.